# phpmailer composer required failed

Tags: installation, phpmailer

I am working on a school project and would like to add a mailing system. When I enter `composer require phpmailer / phpmailer` 
in my terminal I get this error: 
`Script @ auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.`

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure if they were in your actual command, but in what you posted here you've got spaces where they shouldn't be. Try `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer`.

Comment: I tried the command back again and it still gives the same error.

Comment: PHPMailer has no composer scripts, so it may be that there is something else in your composer.json file that's breaking. You could try `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer --no-scripts` which might get PHPMailer installed, but you may find you get other problems later on.

Comment: Thank you! Now the installation worked!